# Painting a JComponent without adding it to a container

Tags: java, swing, rendering, paint, fullscreen

I've implemented a custom `JPanel`, whose paint method I've extended to do a lot of manual rendering in full screen mode. Now I would like to integrate another `JComponent` to this (in my case a `JPanel` that contains a `JScrollpane` with a `JTextPane` as its viewport) that should appear on top of my first panel, but because my custom rendering pipeline is complex, adding the `JComponent` to my panel and having it painted the traditional way through the AWT system is not an option (I tried and it's quirky at best, not functional at worst), so my question is: is it possible to manually order the `JComponent` to be painted at one point in my program by calling its regular paint method without tying it to a `JContainer` and if yes, how do I do this?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: N.B.  If you cannot get it working with the advice already offered, I suggest you post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) of your best effort.

Answer (score 3):

See the `LabelRenderTest.java` source on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe/5853992#5853992).  The label is eventually drawn to screen, but it is painted to `BufferedImage` before ever being displayed.

[image]

The important line of the source is..

```
textLabel.setSize(textLabel.getPreferredSize());
```

Comment: Also consider `RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON`.

Comment: @trashgod:  Isn't anti-aliasing automatically enabled for a `JLabel`?  Or are you referring to the rendering of the `BufferedImage`?  I would not have thought it was relevant at that stage.

Comment: The hint should be set on the context returned by `createGraphics()`, before any painting. Conveniently, `createGraphics()` returns a `Graphics2D` object, and it should get a `dispose()` when done.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at CellRendererPane and see how for example BasicTableUI paints component images with it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just call the normal paint method on the object and pass the Graphics you want it to paint on.  However, this is just going to paint it and it sounds like you want it to possibly scroll which means you will need to add it to your custom JPanel. In that case just add the panel and you a layout manager that will place the component where you need it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this doesn't work. I call the paint method of the JComponent inside the paint method of my JPanel (and passing it the Graphics object) but the JComponent isn't rendered. It does render when I add it to the panel, but as I explained I don't want that because the result is very suboptimal, to say the least.

Comment: Are you painting it before of after you do other painting in the panel?

Comment: In my program it should paint somewhere in the middle of my rendering pipeline, but for testing purposes I've tried adding it right at the end of the paint method but it doesn't work. I've also made sure I reset all the transforms, colour, strokes etc of the Graphics2D object before passing it to the paint method of the JComponent.

Answer (score 2):

You should set size for the component. Then to position it use your Graphics' translate(x,y) to position the component in desired Point.

Comment: Size of the component is set positioned on initialisation. But the component doesn't show when I invoke its paint method.

Answer (score 0):

if there is any container higher level in the hierarchy you can use

```
validate(); repaint();
```

pair to do that.

if not you can change it's size or bounds ( like +1 , -1 ) at the end to make it repaint itself.