# Rendering a Java Component to an image file

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, awt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Swing : Obtain `Image` of JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe)

How do you save what a Java GUI Component displays to an image file?

E.g. rendering a JPanel as a PNG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
JPanel panel = ...
...
...
File yourFileHere = ...
...
...
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
panel.paint(g);
g.dispose();

try{
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", yourFileHere);
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Note that `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` would only make sense if the GUI components had transparency.

Answer (score 1):

that would be descibed and with excelent examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe) by @Andrew Thompson, but you can learn more than that by reading [2D Graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) and examples for that [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Catalog0261__2D-Graphics.htm)