# Paint another component in paintComponent

Tags: java, swing

I use SwingPaintDemo2 from Java Tutorials:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/painting/SwingPaintDemo2Project/src/painting/SwingPaintDemo2.java

I modified it like this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // Draw Text
    g.drawString("This is my custom Panel!",10,20);

    JLabel c = new JLabel("Label");
    c.paint(g);
}
```

g.drawString works fine. But how can I paint JLabel from this method? It doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to set a size to your label.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // Draw Text
    g.drawString("This is my custom Panel!",10,20);

    JLabel c = new JLabel("Label");
    c.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 30);
    c.paint(g);
}
```

Comment: You should try to avoid clobbering the passed `Graphics` object. Instead, use a copy `Graphics gCopy = g.create()`.

Comment: c.setBounds - I haven't even thought about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

See the `LabelRenderTest.java` source on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe/5853992#5853992).  The label is eventually drawn to screen, but it is painted to `BufferedImage` before ever being displayed.

[image]

The important line of the source is..

```
textLabel.setSize(textLabel.getPreferredSize());
```

Comment: your Examples & Html & Images together +1

Comment: @mKorbel 'An image paints a thousand words' ( and gets a few up-votes, usually :).  HTML is just because I could not be bothered figuring the exact position of every text element.  ;)

Comment: I can't to take as your personal attack to my excellent, exciting un-interchangeable, whatever ... form of my English speak :-), as I read some yours edits (or by other NativeSpeakers) then somebody someone must died by laughing :-)