# How do we convert WMF/EMF (MS metafiles) into standard images like JPG or PNG using any Java API?

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I have been stuck in converting WMF/EMF images into standard image format such as JPG or PNG using Java.

What are the best options available?

Comment: people producing WMF/EMF images should be shot to death but for what it's worth: I know for sure that the wonderful (and free) *ImageMagick* used to be able to convert WMF files.  There also used to be a Java wrapper for ImageMagick (called JMagick if memory serves).  So you may want to look in there.  That said as I recall it WMF/EMF are just "shells" or "wrappers" around a variety of formats so it may be a moving target and there may very well be a **lot** of different WMF/EMF files and I'm really not sure this is still dealt with correctly.  It used to work that said...

Answer (score 2):

The [Batik library](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) is a toolkit to handle SVG in Java. There are converters included like [WMFTranscoder](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/transcoder/wmf/tosvg/WMFTranscoder.html) to convert from WMF to SVG and [JPEGTranscoder](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/transcoder/image/JPEGTranscoder.html) and [PNGTranscoder](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/transcoder/image/PNGTranscoder.html) to convert SVG to JPEG/PNG. See [Transcoder API Docs](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/transcoder.html) for more details.

Another alternative is [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). It's not Java but has Java bindings: [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/) and [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/).

Answer (score 1):

wmf is a vector file format. For best results, convert them to `.svg` or `.pdf` format.
I did it in two stages

1) wmf2fig --auto XXXX.wmf

2) fig2pdf --nogv XXXX.fig

I created a python script for bulk conversion

```
import subprocess as sbp
a = sbp.Popen("ls *.wmf",shell=True, stderr=sbp.PIPE, stdout=sbp.PIPE)
filelist = a.communicate()[0].splitlines()

for ele in filelist:
    cmdarg = 'wmf2fig --auto '+ ele.rsplit('.',1)[0]+'.wmf'
    a = sbp.Popen(cmdarg, shell=True, stderr=sbp.PIPE, stdout=sbp.PIPE)
    out = a.communicate()

for ele in filelist:
    cmdarg = 'fig2pdf --nogv '+ ele.rsplit('.',1)[0]+'.fig'
    a = sbp.Popen(cmdarg, shell=True, stderr=sbp.PIPE, stdout=sbp.PIPE)
    out = a.communicate()

cmdarg = 'rm *.fig'
a = sbp.Popen(cmdarg, shell=True, stderr=sbp.PIPE, stdout=sbp.PIPE)
out = a.communicate()
```

Comment: While the answer isn't really about Java, I agree it's probably best to keep the converted result as vector. Batik will be able to convert to SVG.

Answer (score 1):

I've created some wrappers around the Batik package (as mentioned by [vanje's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6792137/1428606)) some time ago, that provides ImageIO support for SVG and WMF/EMF.

With these plugins you should be able to write:

```
ImageIO.write(ImageIO.read(wmfFile), pngFile, "png");
```

Source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/tree/master/imageio/imageio-batik).

While the ImageIO plugins are convenient, im4java and JMagick might still have better format support.

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying your application in a Windows environment, then [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) can handle the conversion for you.

```
    Image image = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), "test.wmf");                
    ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
    loader.data = new ImageData[] { image.getImageData() };
    try(FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("test.png"))
    {
        loader.save(stream, SWT.IMAGE_PNG);
    }
    image.dispose();
```

The purpose of SWT is to provide a Java wrapper around native functionality, and in this case it is calling the windows GDI directly to get it to render the WMF.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

1. Get (or make) a Java component that can render the files in question.
2. Create a `BufferedImage` the same size as the component needs to display the image.
3. Get the `Graphics` object from the `BufferedImage`.
4. Call `renderComponent.paintComponent(Graphics)`
5. Save the image using one of the `ImageIO.write()` variants.

See my answer to [Swing: Obtain Image of JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879) for steps 2-5.  Step 1. is something I'd ask Google about.

Comment: Can show me a piece of code..So that I can understand..I could not create an image(java.awt.Image) out of the file in question. Which again raises an issue in creating BufferedImage..Hope you understand.