# Creating a small images from JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, screen-capture

I'm writing simple slide program in Java. In that program, I draw lines, ellipses, rectangles and etc in each slide. What is more, like a powerpoint I want to show all of my slides' symbolic small pictures on the JList.

How should I create small images from all elements in JPanel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at capturing a panel's image using [*Screen Image*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/), discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7035764/230513).

Addendum: See also [`ComponentImageCapture`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5853992/230513).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your task correct, you must inherit from JPanel and overload method `paintComponent(Graphics g)`. Inside you can write something like `g.drawLine(0,0, 10, 10)`