# Translucent components inside JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, translucency

I have class MyPanel that extends from JPanel. MyPanel class has JLabel component which holds an icon.

My question is how can i paint/render this JLabel component to get translucent effect (see through icon) inside MyPanel class (not create xxxJLabel extends JLabel class and override paintComponents method).

Thank you

Comment: no it's not i try to override method painComponent(Graphics g) of MyPanel class but no luck

Comment: The answer below by: Andrew Thompson should cover it. Make sure you upvote him as he has put in considerable effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to provide a translucent image to the `JLabel`.  That might be done with a standard label, before `setIcon()` or similar is called, or alternately by extending `JLabel` and overriding the `setIcon()` method to do the same.

#### E.G. of 2nd technique

[image]

#### Code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.net.URL;

class TransparentIcon {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String imgURL =
            "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" +
            "a1ab0af4997654345d7a949877f8037e";
        final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(imgURL));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);

                JPanel  p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,3));
                for (int ii=0; ii<6; ii++) {
                    TransparentLabel tl = new TransparentLabel();
                    tl.setOpacity((ii+1)/6f);
                    tl.setIcon(icon);
                    p.add(tl);
                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p);
            }
        });
    }
}

class TransparentLabel extends JLabel {

    float opacity = 1f;

    public void setOpacity(float opacity) {
        this.opacity = opacity;
    }

    private Icon getTranslucentIcon(Icon icon) {

        if (icon!=null) {
            BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                icon.getIconWidth(),
                icon.getIconHeight(),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
            AlphaComposite ac = AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,
                opacity);
            g.setComposite(ac);
            icon.paintIcon(this,g,0,0);
            g.dispose();

            return new ImageIcon(bi);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setIcon(Icon icon) {
        super.setIcon( getTranslucentIcon(icon) );
    }
}
```

---

#### Update

> I just wonder how it can be done if i get Graphics of JLabel inside MyPanel class and change its visual appearance?

[LabelRenderTest.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe/5853992#5853992) renders a `JLabel` to a `BufferedImage` so that it can be used for custom rendering inside the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.

[image]

Note though:  I don't quite understand what the advantage of the `JLabel` is in your use-case.  I was using it in that example in order to render HTML.  If I only had an image, I'd use the image directly (e.g. `Graphics.drawImage(Image,int,int,ImageObserver)`) and never create the label.

Comment: hi you misunderstood my idea! From inside MyPanel class I want to set Component JLabel to be translucent by invoking method JLabel.getGraphics() then doing translucent stuff here

Comment: Perhaps, but your idea is just silly.  Never call `getGraphics()` (unless you *really* know what you are doing).  Also, you are confusing the strategy with the goal.  I still don't understand the goal because you have yet to state it clearly.  You keep focusing on how you want to achieve the goal (i.e. the flawed strategy).

Comment: @Final: I agree strongly with Andrew -- you don't want to use the Graphics object of a component obtained via getGraphics. For one, it won't persist on redraws. If I were you, I'd go with Andrew's suggestions (1+).

Comment: Thank you! I just wonder how it can be done if i get Graphics of JLabel inside MyPanel class and change its visual apperance?

Comment: hmmm.. dont really understand the problem nor the sugested solutions: all that's needed is a transparent _icon_, right? Dont see any need to subclass any _component_ - a utility containing the icon- transparentizing code is enough, anyLabel.setIcon(transparentize(myIcon)). My missing something is a not-zero probability, as the solution comes from @Andrew :-) What am I missing?

Comment: @kleopatra  Hey, I can't really say I understand this question either.  I was just taking a few 'stabs in the dark' because I was bored & there was an opportunity for screen shots. ;)

Comment: hach ... lame excuse for unnecessary subclassing :-)