# Getting started with Drawing and the 2D API

Tags: java, swing, graphics, java-2d

I'm trying to integrate some drawing functionality into my program.

I have a JLabel that has an image set on it.

I want to write a method to return my image:

```
public Graphics getImage(){
    Graphics g = currentImage;
    return g
}
```

But I don't know how to convert it from a JLabel to a graphics object. Then as a simple test I want to draw a line on this image:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {  
    g.drawLine(20, 500, 700, 600);
}
```

Some help with getting started on this would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw on a JLabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466030/how-to-draw-on-a-jlabel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of `JLabel` and place all the drawing code there.

Comment: But I don't have a paintComponent Method. I only have: myJLabel.setIcon(imageLocation);

?

Comment: If the label contains an image, draw direct to the image rather than extend `JLabel`.

Comment: All Swing components implement a paintComponent() method.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a JLabel that has an image set on it.

Create a copy of the image (`BufferedImage image2..`) and put `image2` in the label.

When you need to draw, call `image2.getGraphics()` for a `Graphics` object, or `image2.createGraphics()` for a `Graphics2D` object.

---

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7133370/418556) for examples of creating and using images.

[image]