# JButton and JField labels/text?

Tags: java, html, swing, jbutton, multiline

I have a `JButton` that I would like to fill in with text that would spread in two lines, however, when I type in the test and use `"\n"` or `"\r"` I still get the text on one line.

This is the case with the elements of my `jList` as well.

Thanks

Comment: how about "\n\r", that usually works for me

Comment: BTW 1) What is a `jField`?  A `JTextField` will ignore new lines using either technique shown here.  2) Never use `\n` or `\r`, instead use `System.getProperty("line.seperator")`.

Answer (score 8):

Use HTML

```
JButton button = new JButton("<html><body>line 1 <br /> line 2</body></html>");
```

Comment: Interesting...  Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1) For a more complex example (which avoids having to calculate where to put the `<br>`), see [LabelRenderTest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe/5853992#5853992).  2) See also [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) in the Java Tutorial, and especially note what it says about disabled components.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, JButton admits HTML. However `<body>` is not really necessary:

```
JButton button = new JButton("<html> mylabel <br /> mylabel continues on a newline </html>");
```

[[ taken from [New Line \n is not working in JButton.setText("fnord\nfoo") ;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503280/new-line-n-is-not-working-in-jbutton-settextfnord-nfoo) ]]