# New Line \n is not working in JButton.setText("fnord\nfoo") ;

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, multiline

On a JButton, I want to list information on multiple lines. I tried `\n` as a new line character but it didn't work. The following code:

```
JButton.setText("fnord\nfoo") ;
```

will be displayed as:

```
fnordfoo
```

How do I force a line break?

Comment: Am i seeing things, or did you just ask a question which you answered two seconds later?

Comment: @ForgiveMeI'mAN00b I did not answer it two seconds later, I answered directly with the question itself. There is an option to directly answer your own question on the Ask-a-question-form.

Comment: Stack overflow is meant to be a question-answer style forum to share knowledge and seek answers to problems you're having with your code. Asking and answering a question that you commonly face is a good way to share knowledge and it then becomes a resource for others to use.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

JButton accepts HTML, so for the line break to work use:

```
 JButton.setText("<html>fnord<br />foo</html>");
```

Comment: Just don't use too much HTML in Swing labels.

Comment: See also [Word-wrap in JButtons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766175/word-wrap-in-jbuttons/5767825#5767825) & [Append text in JLabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717121/append-text-in-jlabel/9717360#9717360).