# JButton.setText() in a for loop java

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jbutton

I'm trying to get a two line text in a JButton

The text is suppose to display between  and 
 also between /> and  [just like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503280/new-line-n-is-not-working-in-jbutton-settextfnord-nfoo)
but for some reason, it is not working in my for loop

```
  JButton title[] = new JButton[6];
  JButton button[] = new JButton[30];
  String[] titleText = {"World Religion", "New Title", "New Title", "New Title", "New Title", "New Title"};


  //
  for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
     title[i] = new JButton();
     title[i].setText("<html> <br /> </html>"+titleText[i]);
     add(title[i]); 
  }
```

Comment: because you aren't appending it between the `<html>` tags?

Comment: How can i do it then? @Origineil

Comment: Not sure why you want to out a blank line before or after the text, but you should consider using the buttons margins as an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the text between the `<html>` and `</html>` tags as such:

`title[i].setText("<html><br/>" + titleText[i] + "</html>");`

The content inclosed between the tags `<html></html>` tells the button to interpret it as HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're trying to split each title into lines using the space as a delimiter. If that's the case, I think this should do it:

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
   title[i] = new JButton();
   title[i].setText("<html>" + titleText[i].replace(" ", "<br />") + "</html>");
   add(title[i]); 
}
```