# Write multipleline text into jButton in Netbeans IDE, java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton

In jButton,i want to write a title or text on button and it will look like

```
Advance
Search
Option
```

But the button text look like

```
AdvanceSearchOption
```

It won't take new line. I try change some properties but it won't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503280/new-line-n-is-not-working-in-jbutton-settextfnord-nfoo

Comment: @FastSnail, Can it do by properties of that button ?

Comment: yes `<html>Advance<br />Search<br />Option</html>`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503280/new-line-n-is-not-working-in-jbutton-settextfnord-nfoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on you button then btn[jButton] - Properties tab will appear.
Then click text field and paste

```
<html>Advance<br />Search<br />Option</html>
```

Hope it will work