# Unable to perform a line break for jButton

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JButton and JField labels/text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768694/jbutton-and-jfield-labels-text)

I try to do a line break for jButton in java swing.

```
    public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
private JButton getJButton_discussion() {
    if (jButton_discussion == null) {
        jButton_discussion = new JButton();
        jButton_discussion.setBounds(new Rectangle(228, 63, 344, 97));
        jButton_discussion.setText("Discussion" + newline + "A place to duscuss latest events");

    }
```

However, my "Discussion" and the words after it still appear in the same line. It does not perform a line break. Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: Use HTML. Search this site for this question as it's been asked and answered many many times.

Comment: I done using the <html> tag. Thanks a lot.