# Java Applet String overflow

Tags: java, user-interface

Hey I have a Java applet that calculates the binomial expansion, however when the string is long the string overflows the applet and you can only see a portion of it, how can I fix this, so i have to add a scroll bar or what would be the easiest thing to do? I use :

```
g.drawString(ans  ,10,100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `JTextField` or `JTextArea` to the applet.  The text field will automatically allow scrolling.  The text area can be added to a `JScrollPane`.

---

If it is vital to draw the text in the `Graphics`, perhaps look to rendering it using a multi-line `JLabel`, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5853992/418556).

[image]