# How to get mouseover/pop-up effect on button?

Tags: java, swing, mouseover, jbutton

How to get the mouseover effects on `JButton` which should be similar to the effect which we will get on **mouseover of tags in Stackoveflow?  E.G.**

[image: Pop-up help]

Comment: This should give you plenty of answers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+mouseover

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`JComponent.setToolTipText(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setToolTipText%28java.lang.String%29).  The tool-tip supports HTML to some extent, but not to the extent of providing the functionality of the links at the bottom of the SO tag pop-ups.

To do that, you'd need to swap the tool-tip for a `JWindow`/`JEditorPane` where you'd need to 'wire it together' yourself.  Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10093168/418556) that uses a `JWindow` (to display `BufferedImage` instances).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [setRolloverIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29). Here is an [example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing/button_OtherIcon.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
Icon normalIcon = new ImageIcon("normal-icon.png"); // Icon for normal situations
JButton button = new JButton(); // initialize the button
button.setIcon(normalIcon); // set the normal situation icon

Icon rollOverIcon = new ImageIcon("roll-over.png"); // Icon for roll over (hovering effect)
button.setRolloverIcon(rollOverIcon); // Set the icon attaching with the roll-over event
```