# How do I make a Windows 7 Tooltip in Java

Tags: java, windows, swing, windows-7, tooltip

I've been looking everywhere online but I have found no answers to this little problem. In Windows 7 (and in Vista, I think,) you have a nice rounded silver looking tooltip that looks way better than the old yellow boxed crappy looking one.  The "How do I make a Windows 7 Tooltip in Java - Stack Overflow" tip below is how it appears.

[image]

So in Java, I want to do exactly that, make the nice new Windows tooltip. The problem is I don't know how to.

Outside of the following simple code is a main method that simply creates an object of this class 'Tooltip'.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Tooltip extends JFrame {
public Tooltip() {

    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JButton button = new JButton("Tooltip Button");
    button.setToolTipText("Tooltip");
    add(button);

    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(250, 160);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the try/multi catch, I set the Look and Feel to the operating system that the program is currently running on. If I were to run this program on Windows, I would get the crummy yellow tooltip.

So what changes do I have to make to the code so that I will get a nice silver tooltip if the program is running on a Windows operating system?

Comment: Just a suggestion, if you are so afraid of typing, then why you wrote this line `catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e)`, why not you simply write `catch(Exception e)`, that will do the same thing, since it will catch no matter what exception arises and will reduce your typing work too :-)

Comment: DYM like in the screenshot I edited into the question?

Comment: Thanks @nIcEcOw I was not aware you could do that. I feel old now :D I will probably update the code example above now.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you very much for taking the time to do that. This question has been on my mind for a couple of months now and I hope it will be answered. I've looked everywhere, but found nothing, so I can use all the help I can get :)

Answer (score 3):

You might need to use a component based on a `JWindow` for this, as in my answer to [Preview window (like Windows 7 taskbar shows for opened applications)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090622/preview-window-like-windows-7-taskbar-shows-for-opened-applications/10093168#10093168).

[image]

For the rounded corners, see [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html).

[image: Shaped window]

For the slight gradient (squints), paint the BG using a [`GradientPaint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GradientPaint.html).

A tool-tip provides a functionality not included in that simple example linked.  But it is a starting point.  Make sure you don't accidentally drop the Windows 7 style tool-tip to pre Windows 7 users or users of other OS'.  In the same way you feel the 'square/yellow BG' tool-tip clashes, they will not find the clashing style to be 'pretty'.  Which leads to..

---

The best way to achieve the effect is through a custom PLAF based on [The Synth Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html).

> Creating a custom look and feel, or modifying an existing one, can be a daunting task. The `javax.swing.plaf.synth` package can be used to create a custom look and feel with much less effort. You can create a Synth look and feel either programatically or through the use of an external XML file.

Comment: This preview thingy is COOL :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw  You mean in the animated GIF?  Thanks.  :)

Comment: This small image that comes up, as a tooltip. I remember once I asked you about how to animate an image, you told me about that software you made, on that site of yours, I try my hands on that, learned how to put three images in one. For the rest, you are MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson but I am sure there is another way to properly achieve this, whether it is in the API or some other well known or used external library. I know that it is possible to get these tooltip styles because they are in eclipse everywhere! (eclipse was written in Java of course :D)

Comment: @Shrederator eclipse is java, but not Swing