# How do I change the tooltip look and feel to the system's?

Tags: java, swing, windows-7, tooltip, look-and-feel

I have added the line to set look and feel to system. This is found to work because the scroll bars have changed.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

But when I set a tooltip to my JTabbedPane's tab, it does not show the system's look and feel for tooltips. Why is this? Screenshots are below.

System's look and feel:

[image]

Java's look and feel(?):

[image]

I want to set my tooltip to look like the system's which is in the first screenshot. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you called `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);` before changing the LAF?

Comment: You may find [How do I make a Windows 7 Tooltip in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11166318/1048330) useful.

Answer (score 2):

Much work without the complete effect:

- for getting the background you need a custom implemenation of ToolTipUI: basically extend BasicToolTipUI and take over the painting
- register the custom ui delegate with the UIManager so that it is used instead of the default
- theoretically, you can achieve the rounded corners of the window (the one containing the tooltip) by using a shaped window (public api in jdk7, a half-official workaround available for jdk6), you would need a shaped window. Practically, there is no way (except extreme hacking) to make the ToolTipManager use that window