# Top Menu(close, minimize, maximize) Java

Tags: java, swing, menu, toolbar, look-and-feel

How to change Look and Feel for the ToolBar, the top menu (where the buttons to close, minimize, maximize)

Is it possible to like something change? (Add, delete button, assign a background)
What is import is required to create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the background image of a `JButton` you could have a look at this: [Swing Tutorial: JButton](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JButton.html) which shows the use of the `new JButton(String text,ImageIcon imgIco)` to create a `JButton` with an `ImageIcon` and `String`.

To set the colour of the background and text you could use `setBackground(Color c)` and `setForeground(Color c)`

or

Alternatively just customize Look and Feel color scheme by setting an appropriate supported [Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) and then [change the color scheme/size etc of its components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/color.html) thier are hundreds of things you can change for every component see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#primary) for them all.

To *customize* the *Exit*, *Minimize* and *Maximize* Toolbar buttons this can also be using the Look and Feel ( [Custom design for Close/Minimize buttons on JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913058/custom-design-for-close-minimize-buttons-on-jframe) ):

[image: Metal]  [image: Windows]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameCloseButtonsByLookAndFeel {

    FrameCloseButtonsByLookAndFeel() {
        String[] names = {
                UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName(), 
                UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName()
        };
        for (String name : names) {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(name);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // very important to get the window decorations.
            JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            JFrame f = new JFrame(UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

            JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            f.setContentPane(gui);

            JTree tree = new JTree();
            tree.setVisibleRowCount(4);
            gui.add(tree, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

            gui.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(3,15)));

            JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
            gui.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            for (int ii=1; ii<5; ii++) {
                toolbar.add(new JButton("Button " + ii));
                if (ii%2==0) {
                    toolbar.addSeparator();
                }
            }

            f.pack();

            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FrameCloseButtonsByLookAndFeel();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way to change frame titlebar look is to set LookAndFeel before you create your frame.
Probably this is what you are looking for - http://www.jtattoo.net/ScreenShots.html