# Drawing own frame with 3 buttons

Tags: java, swing, frame

The title may not be suitable, but here's the complete explanation

What I need is that my frame should have 3 buttons (Minimize, Maximize, Close) but the border of the frame should be customized (some color/gradient).

See this:
[image: Preview]
<sub>(source: [getintopc.com](http://getintopc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/corel-videostudio-pro-x6-free-download-features.jpg))</sub>

Edit : I have not started coding, because I have no idea where to start from

Comment: You probably want to create your own complete look and feel. There's no one real answer to this question. Take a look at [**How to Write a Custom Look and Feel**](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/09/12/how-to-write-custom-look-and-feel.html)

Comment: If you want to customize the frame, then you would draw it yourself. As you draw the whole frame, you can draw as many buttons as you want but you'll have to handle the events. By the way, you can change _Look and Feel_ on a single component, JFrame.

Comment: @alexey : you are right, i just want to modify exactly the outer border of JFrame, will you suggest some way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Add the desired internal frame icons, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10360374/230513), to a container in an undecorated frame, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2166500/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Some Look and Feels support JFrame decorations, for example the standard one, Metal, does:

[image: Frame with LaF decorated border]

You can check whether the LaF supports decorations or not by using [`LookAndFeel.getSupportsWindowDecorations()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/LookAndFeel.html#getSupportsWindowDecorations%28%29).

By modifying the LaF you can change how frame decorations are painted.

Alternatively, you can create a frame without decorations at all. Call [`setUndecorated(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29) on a frame instance:

[image: Frame without decorations]

So you can easily paint whatever you want in the content pane. Yet such window cannot be easily moved, resized, minimized or maximized unless you implement these features yourself.

You can find interesting the article [Windows Java tip: How to control window decorations](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2009/02/windows_java_tip_how_control_window_decorations).

---

I used the following [AFrame class](http://malyek.net/misc/stack-overflow/AFrame.java):

```
public class AFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("A Frame");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.setSize(200, 100);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

To create frame without border:

- Remove line `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);`
- Add line `frame.setUndecorated(true);`

---

**Update:** I found series of articles on how add frame decorations to Nimbus Look and Feel:

- [Nimbus Look and Feel frame decorations - 1st step: something functional](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/anthra/archive/2014/02/26/nimbus-look-and-feel-frame-decorations-1st-step-something-functional)
- [2nd step: something iconic](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/anthra/archive/2014/02/28/nimbus-look-and-feel-frame-decorations-2nd-step-something-iconic)
- [3rd step: something cloudy](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/anthra/archive/2014/03/02/nimbus-look-and-feel-frame-decorations-3rd-step-something-cloudy)

The frame from the 3rd step looks this way:
[Nimbus Look and Feel frame decorations: 3rd step rendering http://weblogs.java.net/sites/default/files/ThirdStep.png](http://weblogs.java.net/sites/default/files/ThirdStep.png)

You can use the code in these articles as the base to implement your own frame decorations.