# Simple Tree-Viewer Library

Tags: java, image, treeview

I'm looking for a simple tree viewer. It should produce a image (like png) of a tree with its nodes and relations.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Build a [JTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) with your data. Then search for how to get an image from Swing components like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe).

[image]