# Take a "screenshot" of 3rd party applet in my webpage

Tags: java, image, applet, screenshot, awtrobot

I have a third party Java applet that I am going to embed in my webpage *but I don't have access to the applet code.*

But I want to create a button on my page on clicking which will create a screenshot of the applet (but not the whole screen).  I tried using the Robot class but that would take the whole screen which I don't want

```
BufferedImage screencapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(
    new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()) );
```

I was looking over the net and found code but those require access to the applet which I don't have.

Is it possible to do it using java?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two options.

### 2nd applet

- Use a 2nd applet to get a reference to the applet, using [`AppletContext.getApplet(name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#getApplet%28java.lang.String%29).
- Call [`Applet.getLocationOnScreen()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen%28%29) for the co-ordinates.
- It is your page, so unless the applet size is set using percentages, you know the width x height to capture.
- Either use sockets to connect to the desktop/CLI app. that takes the screen-shot, or use the applet to take the screen-shot.  Either way, it will require the applet to be trusted.

### Extend the applet

Extend the original applet & add a new method to return or export an image of the current applet surface.  See [ComponentImageCapture.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe/5853992#5853992) for an example.

Options for exporting the image:

- Deploy the applet using [JWS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) - use the JNLP file API to export the image to the local file-system.
- Digitally sign the applet export the image to the local file-system using the more common `JFileChooser`/`File`.
- Pass it back to the host site, which can be done by a sand-boxed applet.