# Converting ACM graphics window to image file

Tags: java, image, graphics, png, acm-java-libraries

I'm new to this website and relatively new to Java.

I've created a Java application that uses the ACM graphics package and extends a [`GraphicsProgram`](http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/acm/program/GraphicsProgram.html). I want to now be able to convert the contents of my graphical output window into an image file such as a png or jpeg. How to do that?

Comment: This answer was deleted for some reason, but: you can use a screenshot application.

Answer (score 1):

See [`ComponentImageCapture`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5853992/418556), which can capture and save an image of a `Component` or `JComponent`.

[image]