# Is that possible to grab pixels from AWT component?

Tags: java, image, awt, screenshot, awtrobot

I know that it is possible to capture lightweight Swing component picture by calling `paint(Graphics g)` method on the `BufferedImage.getGraphics()` instance. 
Like here: [Swing: Obtain Image of JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe)

Is it possible to grab AWT component's contents as an `Image`?

So far, I think of `java.awt.Robot` solution only:

1. Get AWT component bounds
2. Make screenshot with specific bounds.

Comment: Simple answer: try it. But seeing as the AWT widgets are actually drawn by the OS, this might be a hugely platform-dependent question.

Comment: Huh.. Good question.  Please try it and report back so we can try it on other OS.  I had never considered AWT when I answered the linked question.

Comment: @MvG I tried that in a variety of ways: `GraphicsEnvironment`, `CellRendererPane`, tuned `Graphics` object via `setColor(component.getForeground())` and `g.setFont(component.getFont());` calls. Even on windows it usually returns solid black rectangle or rectangle with the component foreground color.

Comment: @AndrewThompson seems like grabbing screenshots is the only feasible solution, because the direct paint messages for the native control are usually deeply hidden inside the native code.

Comment: @OstapAndrusiv, I'm not surprised by your findings. Perhaps you should turn them into an answer to this question. You probably should give details on *what* components you tried to grab, as swing components inherit from `Component` as well. So not all of them are heavyweight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the only working solution is to:

1. Find component bounds in screen coordinate system.
2. Use `java.awt.Robot` class to create screen capture of the area, which corresponds to the component.