# Java - Converting a string in JTextArea to an image

Tags: java, string, image

I have a string which is displayed in my program, but I'm wondering how I would convert the output of the string into an image identical to the original string. No idea if this can be done.

I would like the output to be exactly what is is the JTextArea. Is this possible and if so what should I look into?

Comment: *"I would like the output to be exactly what is is the JTextArea."*   Using what PLAF?  At what width/height?  Including the text selection and cursor?  Most importantly.. why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

assylias beat me to it, but seen as I was so close I thought I'd post it anyway

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea text;

    public TestFrame() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setTitle("Text");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        text = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane(text));

        JButton btnPrint = new JButton("Print");
        add(btnPrint, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        btnPrint.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(text.getWidth(), text.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
                text.printAll(g2d);
                g2d.dispose();

                try {
                    ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("StringToGraphics.png"));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        text.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        text.setColumns(15);
        text.setLineWrap(true);
        text.setText("I have a string which is displayed in my program, but I'm wondering how I would convert the output of the string into an image identical to the original string. No idea if this can be done.\n\nI would like the output to be exactly what is is the JTextArea. Is this possible and if so what should I look into?");

        setSize(200, 300);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

From this

[image: The Frmae]

to this

[image: The result]

Comment: +1   See also [ComponentImageCapture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe/5853992#5853992).

Comment: Any way to make the background transparent?

Comment: @CardinalSystem That would mostly likely require you to make the text area transparent (ie setOpaque), but i wouldn’t do that on a live component which is displayed in the screen, which makes more complicated

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ScreenImage](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) to create an image from a component using the `createImage` method. In summary, here is what it does under the hood (using a JLabel):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws AWTException, IOException {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
            JLabel text = new JLabel("text");
            frame.add(text);
            frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

            BufferedImage img = getImage(text);
            try {
                ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("C:/temp/img.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

private static BufferedImage getImage(JComponent c) {
    Rectangle region = c.getBounds();
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(region.width, region.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
    g2d.translate(-region.x, -region.y);
    g2d.setColor(c.getBackground() );
    g2d.fillRect(region.x, region.y, region.width, region.height);
    c.paint(g2d);
    g2d.dispose();
    return image;
}
```