# Printing JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to print a JTextArea through a printer, but text from JTextArea is not visible in print file i.e. .xps file.

```
bprint.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      try {
         int num;
         JFrame f1 = new JFrame("PrintJob");
         Toolkit tkp = p1.getToolkit();
         Properties prop = new Properties();
         PrintJob pjp = tkp.getPrintJo(f1, "Printjob", prop);
         Graphics g = pjp.getGraphics();
         p1.print(g);
         g.dispose();
         pjp.end();
      } catch (Exception e109) {
         System.out.println(e109);
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Please put in the effort ask an actual answerable question and to provide pertinent details so that we have half a chance to understand what may be wrong. If you won't put in the effort to clarify your problem, why should we put in the effort to try to help you?

Answer (score 2):

That's not really how printing is done, you should be passing the PrintJob a Printable, which will then tell you when it wants something printed

Take a look at [Printing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/) for more details

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764634/printing-a-jframe-and-its-components/12765916#12765916), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665089/control-the-size-of-the-panel-on-printed-page/12665357#12665357) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894064/java-converting-a-string-in-jtextarea-to-an-image/11894319#11894319)

Answer (score 1):

Note, you're trying to print from a JFrame created de novo within your ActionListener, one that has no JTextArea, and certainly no text component that has any code input from any user. I presume that there's a real visualized GUI out there that you are intent on printing, but if so, your code above doesn't approach a solution because it is creating its own GUI, one that is never displayed and with a JTextArea that never gets text, and then tries to print it. The solution is to try to get a reference to the actual visualized JTextArea and then to extract its text.