# Creating a virtual monitor/virtual display device

Tags: windows, driver, monitor

I'm trying to create a "virtual monitor" in Windows (XP & newer). For example, let's say my desktop looks like this:

[image]

I want to add a monitor virtually so it looks like this without any change in hardware:
[image]

How do I do this? Do I add a virtual driver? Or trick Windows into thinking there is new hardware?

Comment: This question is off topic here.  It is a duplicate of [this Superuser question](http://superuser.com/questions/91786/where-can-i-find-vista-win7-virtual-display-drivers)

Comment: considering there might be a programming outcome, I think it fits on StackOverflow. It's also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922174/creating-a-virtual-monitor-the-display-device?rq=1 but neither have valid answers.

Comment: considering there might be a programming outcome, I think it fits on StackOverflow.

Comment: Voted to reopen - I need this kind of program for programming

Comment: There is hope, here: http://virtualmonitor.github.io/  Looks like a work-in-progress and only supports windows 2000 - windows 7, but he's looking for help with windows 7 - 8.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, once upon I was in same problem and someone reccomended to me to override EDID data.

The EDID (Extended display identification data) data structure have all the info of your graphic card and other video sources.

You can see a tutorial for [how modify EDID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487330.aspx) here.

The tutorial only applies to Win 7, Win server 2008 and Win Vista...

I don't try the following because I'm a bit afraid of manipulating these data, but... if you're average in these stuff you could try ;)

---

If you prefer a hardware solution, perhaps DVI Detective may help you. In [his website](http://www.gefen.com/kvm/ext-dvi-edidn.jsp?prod_id=4714) they claim that DVI "provides a virtual EDID". Also, this hardware protects the EDID data, so, there's lower risk to do very much damage...

Hope this helps :)