# how to get the image of a Swing widget?

Tags: java, swing, java-canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Swing : Obtain `Image` of JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe)

I am working on a little drag-and-drop Java GUI builder.  It works so far, but the widgets I'm dragging and dropping are just rectangles I'm dynamically drawing on a canvas.

If I have a rectangle that represents a widget like a JButton, is there a way for me to create a JButton, set the size and get the image of that JButton if it was drawn on the screen?  Then I could paint the image to the screen instead of just my boring rectangle.

For example, I'm currently doing this to draw a (red) rectangle:

```
public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;
    int height = 100;
    int width = 150;

    graphics.setColor(Color.red);
    graphics.drawRect(x, y, height, width);
}
```

How can I do something like:

```
public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;
    int height = 100;
    int width = 150;

    JButton btn = new JButton();
    btn.setLabel("btn1");
    btn.setHeight(height); // or minHeight, or maxHeight, or preferredHeight, or whatever; swing is tricky ;) 
    btn.setWidth(width);
    Image image = // get the image of what the button will look like on screen at size of 'height' and 'width'

    drawImage(image, x, y, imageObserver);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you drag JButtons in a JPanel directly.

Comment: @AndrewThompson You're right!  The answer to that question describes what I want to do.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the suggestion, but that's not what I need.

Comment: @Robert Cool.  If that answers the question here, please feel free to up-vote the (excellent - IMO) accepted answer.  It seems best to leave this question to be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you'll paint your component to an image, and then paint that image wherever you want.  In this case it's okay to call `paint` directly because you're not painting to the screen (but to a memory location).

If you wanted to optimize your code more than I've done here, you can save the image, and just repaint it in a different location whenever it's moved (instead of calculating the image from the button every time the screen repaints).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MainPanel extends Box{

    public MainPanel(){
        super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Create image to paint button to
        BufferedImage buttonImage = new BufferedImage(100, 150, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        final Graphics g2d = buttonImage.getGraphics();

        // Create button and paint it to your image
        JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
        button.setSize(button.getPreferredSize());
        button.paint(g2d);

        // Draw image in desired location
        g.drawImage(buttonImage, 100, 100, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
     final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.add(new MainPanel());
     frame.pack();
     frame.setSize(400, 300);
     frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `g.drawImage(buttonImage, 100, 100, null);`  No need for `null` there. A `Box` is an `ImageObserver`.