# How to export jFrame components to Ms-Word file?

Tags: java, swing

I have created a jFrame with components on it .

Components like jButton, jLabel, jPanel are placed on that jFrame.

I want to export those components to MS-Word file so that I can print them. 
Is there any way to perform this?

Comment: You can paint the frame (and/or its contents) to an image and save that to a file or print the, directly

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575201/how-to-save-a-image-on-jframe/12575259#12575259) or something like this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764634/printing-a-jframe-and-its-components/12765916#12765916) if you just want to print it directly...