# Taking a screenshot of your JFrame programatically

Tags: java, swing, jframe, screenshot, bluej

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Swing : Obtain `Image` of JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe)

Is it possible to take a screenshot of your JFrame programatically? How?

I am using BlueJ. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like your question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe

Comment: And for the 'other' way to do it (not mentioned in the Q&A linked by @CyrilDeba), see [`Robot.createScreenCapture(Rectangle)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).

Comment: This question was asked quite a lot of times on this site, try to search a little bit.