# Print a JFrame to a page Java

Tags: java, swing, printing, jframe, java-2d

How would you print a jFrame in java?

e.g

```
JFrame myJFrame = new JFrame("Window");
printClass.print(myJFrame);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879

Comment: Do you mean like `snapshot`?

Answer (score 3):

please to read (and try code examples)

- [from Oracle tutorial 2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)
- lesson [Printing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html)
- see [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) in the case that you want to printing to the File