# Do a print screen of my java application

Tags: java, jbutton, printscreen

How can I make a print screen of my java application?

```
   saveScreen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: maybe you need use the Robot class, and press the prt sc key automatically

Comment: @user2511414 Make that an answer

Comment: @Thihara NO differences between comments and answers, I just would help, in any order

Comment: kockos answer seem to be an better alternative...

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5853992/418556).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll give another method, it will print out the `Component` you passed in:

```
private static void print(Component comp) {
    // Create a `BufferedImage` and create the its `Graphics`
    BufferedImage image = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
            .getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration()
            .createCompatibleImage(comp.getWidth(), comp.getHeight());
    Graphics graphics = image.createGraphics();
    // Print to BufferedImage
    comp.paint(graphics);
    graphics.dispose();
    // Output the `BufferedImage` via `ImageIO`
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("Image.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You need to at least

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
```

---

To prevent blocking the EDT, `ImageIO.write` shouldn't be invoked on EDT, so replace the `try`-`catch` block with the following:

```
    new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
        private boolean success;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            try {
                // Output the `BufferedImage` via `ImageIO`
                if (ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("Image.png")))
                    success = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            if (success) {
                // notify user it succeed
                System.out.println("Success");
            } else {
                // notify user it failed
                System.out.println("Failed");
            }
        }
    }.execute();
```

And one more thing to import:

```
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
```

Comment: Very well! This was what I wanted.

Comment: @Milton90 `paint` should be call on EDT while `ImageIO.write` shouldn't. It's just an example here. You should manually use `SwingWorker`. Will edit.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of how you can make a capture of the screen:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
BufferedImage capture = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
```

Then, simply pass the `BufferedImage` to a stream that writes its content to a file.

Comment: See also an [example in codota](https://www.codota.com/java/core/scenarios/54932d16da0ac4795805d59a/java.awt.Robot?tag=jdk8_1)