# JXMapkit without visible UI

Tags: java, swing, jxmapkit

Is it possible, to use `JXMapKit` with Java to render e.g. `Openstreetmaps` map images without a visible ui? My use case is to have an commandline application on a server to render map images using `JXMapKit`. Is it possible or is there a better possibility for my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i figured it out. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5853992/1965084) is explained, how to obtain screenshots from controls in Java independent from their visibility.