# javacv - fast screenshot - how to get image

Tags: java, javacv

I just found a good example of JavaCV which using [FFmpegFrameGrabber](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv/FFmpegFrameGrabber.java) to make screenshot code for linux which supposed to be "fast":

```
try {
    int x = 0, y = 0, w = 1366, h = 768;
    FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(":0.0+" + x + "," + y);
    grabber.setFormat("x11grab");
    grabber.setImageWidth(w);
    grabber.setImageHeight(h);
    grabber.start();
    CanvasFrame frame = new CanvasFrame("Screen Capture");

    frame.showImage(grabber.grabImage());

    frame.dispose();
    grabber.stop();
} catch (FrameGrabber.Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

...anyways I'm still not sure how to get image of the screenshot to save in a file. I couldn't find any related example so I do need your advice...

So my question how to get image of screenshot to make possible IO?

Comment: *So my question how to get Image of screenshot to make possible IO?* Uh... what?

Comment: @Turing85  The code above grabber.grabImage() see docs https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv/FFmpegFrameGrabber.java returns Frame which is neither stream nor image :( So how to get a usable screenshot which can be saved on file for example?

Comment: [This class](http://bytedeco.org/javacv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacv/Java2DFrameConverter.html) looks like it can convert a `Frame` into a `BufferedImage`.

Comment: @Turing85 Is there a way not to convert (which may be slow) but to use a standard "how-to-make-screenshot-with-javacv" solution? There should be a byte array for example but I didn't find it my bad :( please help me

Comment: The class I presented is part of the framework you use. I think that this is the "standard-way". OpenCV does not necessarily operate in the "bytearray"-way. `Frame` does not define a method returning a `byte[]`.

Comment: @Turing85 I tried to convert and it kind of working; I am not sure yet concerning how fast the way is anyways please post your answer me to accept it;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [API of JavaCV](http://bytedeco.org/javacv/apidocs/), there is an abstract `FrameConverter<F>` class. The concrete implementation [`Java2DFrameConverter`](http://bytedeco.org/javacv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacv/Java2DFrameConverter.html) looks like what you are looking for.

Comment: I just tried "CanvasFrame frame" and, as I can get it, its scale is by default the minumum one though I set "frame.setSize(100,100)" but still the frame seems to be 10x10 pxl :( I don't get it how to set CanvasFrame width and height correct?

Comment: Look at the API. I cannot do more than this myself.

Comment: I understand but the CanvasFrame maybe has some another way to set width and height?

Comment: Maybe. If it has, you will find it in the API.

Comment: Looking at the API, a `CanvasFrame` has nothing to do with a `Frame`. A `CanvasFrame` is more like ja `JFrame`. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/swing-obtain-image-of-jframe) might help.

Comment: I tried to paint the grabbed and converted screenshot on JLabel in a usual way as "super.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, 500,300,null);" but still I have a strange 10x10  red square in the left upper corner of the frame; I set frame background color as red so it is certainly the frame arftifact or similar which doesn't allow to  make screenshot preview with the FrameCanvas a good looking one :'(

Comment: Have you tried querying the image directly about its width and height?

Comment: I guess image by itself should be fine but to preview screenshots in CanvasFrame causes artifacts issue; A 10x10, as I can get it JFrame's content pane, square is painted over JLabel which contains image :*( Some layers issue or I don't get it...